# GCP - do I need to pay for using google plus sign in in my app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, price

Recently, I received an email from google says "Your free trial has ended."
I have an android app which uses the google plus sign in to authentication.
Do I need to pay for this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pricing

Comment: 1) Google Plus is deprecated. 2) There is no charge but you need a valid Cloud Platform account with a valid credit card assigned to the billing account.

Answer (score 0):

as John Hanley commented Google Plus is deprecated. If you want to know if you are going to be charged for maintaining the usage of your project you just need to take a look on the billing section of your project, if you see any charge related to the service that you want to maintain then you will be charged if you keep using the product

Since your question isn't clear if you need more help on this please share with us a screenshot of your billing resume or the product that you are using to help you with this